# Удалить все инвалидные std::weak_ptr

Tags: c++, указатели, vector

Дело обстоит так, мне необходимо сделать систему подписки на события обработки IP пакетов.

Описал базовой класс слушателя, так же описал класс события:

Слушатель:

```
namespace odin::net::sniffers::listeners {
    class ip {
    public:
        ip(ip const &) = delete;
        ip(ip &&) = delete;

        ip &operator=(ip const &) = delete;
        ip &operator=(ip &&) = delete;

        virtual void received(packets::ip const &packet) = 0;
        virtual ~ip();

    protected:
        ip();
    };
}
```

Событие:

```
namespace odin::net::sniffers {
    class ip;
}

namespace odin::net::sniffers::events {
    class ip {
    public:
        void operator+=(const std::weak_ptr<listeners::ip>& lis);
        void operator-=(const std::weak_ptr<listeners::ip>& lis);

    protected:
        void post(packets::ip const &data);
        void remove_expired();

    private:
        friend class sniffers::ip;
        std::vector<std::weak_ptr<listeners::ip>> m_listeners_;
    };
}
```

Вот, теперь я могу вызывая `+=` оператор подписываться на событие, но дело не в этом, меня интересует факт удаления инвалидных указателей из вектора, перед вызовом события.

Код класса события:

```
namespace odin::net::sniffers::events {
    void ip::operator+=(std::weak_ptr<listeners::ip> const& lis) {
        m_listeners_.push_back(lis);
    }

    void ip::operator-=(const std::weak_ptr<listeners::ip>& lis) {
        m_listeners_
            .erase(std::ranges::find_if(m_listeners_,
            [&](auto const &cur) {
                return cur.lock() == lis.lock();
            }));
    }

    void ip::post(packets::ip const &data) {
        remove_expired();
        for (const std::weak_ptr<listeners::ip>& listener : m_listeners_) {
            listener.lock()->received(data);
        }
    }

    bool expired_ptr(std::weak_ptr<listeners::ip> const& ptr) {
        return ptr.expired();
    }

    void ip::remove_expired() {
        m_listeners_
            .erase(std::ranges::find_if(m_listeners_, expired_ptr));
    }
}
```

Самое интересующее место это `remove_expired`, все ли там нормально, что бы не было такого, что при его вызове например случилось так, что итератор будет инвалидным, и не удалит найденные указатели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что, по вашему, произойдет если невалидных указателей 0 или 2+? Если 2+, то удалены будут не все, а если 0 - `find` вернет `.end()`, передача которого в `.erase()` вызывает `UB`.

Лучше использовать `std::erase_if(m_listeners_, expired_ptr);`, который удалит любое количество невалидных указателей, или не будет делать ничего, если их нет.